# Open a file using Desktop(java.awt)

Tags: java, file, awt, desktop

Am using the following code snippet to open a file,

```
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
 try {
     Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
     File myFile = new File(fileName);
     desktop.open(myFile);
     } catch (IOException ex) {}
 }
```

if the file i try to open is of normal .txt or .pdf any such file types i can able to open the file.

But in some cases,

[image]

As shown above the **Type of file** is **File** , in this scenario the file is not opened.

if i manually open this *File type* file i get open with window and using a text editor i am able to open it.

How should i handle this in java? Please help..

Comment: You suppressed the exception. It should have some information there..

Comment: Since i know that tis file can be viewed with notepad, I tried `ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("Notepad.exe",FileName);    pb.start()` ... and the file opened in a NotePad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows says the type of the file is "file" when there is no extension. This is why there is no default opener, and that is why Java doesn't open the file properly.

You can either rename the file and give it an extension, or use Java to directly execute the program you want to open the file with.

Answer (score 1):

[`#open`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open%28java.io.File%29) method finds the *specified* default app to open the specified file but in `.file` type there is no default app to open the file.You can only specify manually to open it in specific app.So if you set the default application that should open the `.file` and you have to set the default application and [*choose default program*](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/change-file-open-program#1TC=windows-7) to open the file and than run the program.